# passing variables from one function to the other in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript program with 3 functions. The first 2 functions both have the variable values inside and I want to access those variables in the third function but i get an error which says the variables are undefined. 
I tried setting the variables globally outside the function and then accessing them but been having the same errors.

```
var result; 
var result2; 

function getOpens(){

 result = 10;

}

function getClicks(){

  result2 = 6
} 

function getTotal(){

  if(result >= 10 && result2 < 1)
   {
     //DO SOMETHING
 }
} 

 getOpens();
 getClicks();
 getTotal();
```

Im not sure if this is the correct way for accessing variables from other functions. I tried setting the globally but still no luck and the getTotal function is not able to get access to variables result and result2.

Comment: And where are the functions executed?

Comment: the value havent initialize yet because the function getOpens and getClicks are not called

Comment: when will you call the fucntions then

Comment: why don't you pass the variables as function arguments?

Comment: I edited the question, still doesnt work when i call them

Comment: It doesn't do anything because (a) `//DO SOMETHING` is a comment and doesn't do anything and (b) `result2 = 6` doesn't set `result2` to a value that matches `result2 < 1`!

Comment: Look at my answer, you are one tiny change away from it working. Look at your second condition in the if. is 6 < 1?

Comment: yeah i know i put //Do something because im not worried about that yet. my problem is, it is not getting the variable values.

Comment: Im not too concerned about the if statement, just getting the values of the variables which does not work

Comment: But it does, look at the jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the return values from the function in your third function? It works without global variables.

```
function getOpens(){
    return 10;
}

function getClicks(){
    return 6;
}

function getTotal() {
    if(getOpens() >= 10 && getClicks() < 1) {
        //DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

few options

**Option 1 - call functions in getTotal()**

```
function getOpens(){
 return 10;
}

function getClicks(){
    return 6;
} 

function getTotal(){

var result = getOpens(); 
var result2 = getClicks(); 

  if(result >= 10 && result2 < 1)
  {
   //DO SOMETHING
  }
}
```

**Option 2 - pass params with function getTotal()**

```
  function getTotal(opens, myClicks){

  if(opens >= 10 && myClicks< 1)
  {
   //DO SOMETHING
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
var result; 
var result2; 

function getOpens(){
 return 10;
}

function getClicks(){
  return 6;
} 

function getTotal(){
  if(result >= 10 && result2 < 1)
   {
     console.log("DO SOMETHING");
 } else {
   console.log("DO SOMETHING ELSE");
 }
}

result = getOpens();
result2 = getClicks();
getTotal();
```